# How to show Edit mode selection panel

Tags: edit-mode, panel

For a reason in my Blender 3.3.4 I don't have the Edit mode selection panel anymore when I switch to Edit mode (tab):

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/_images/modeling_meshes_selecting_mode-buttons.png

I tried to read the doc [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/modeling/meshes/selecting.html) but I cannot understand where is the option to show it.

EDIT:

Here my interface in edit mode:

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please make a screenshot of your whole interface?

Comment: Of course you don't have it anymore... this manual screenshot you show is from version 2.80, the menu doesn't look like that anymore for quite a while now.

Comment: @moonboots question edited, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nurbs surface object, not a mesh object, you don't have edges or faces in these objects, you can only manipulate vertices. You can still convert it to mesh, just right click > *Convert To > Mesh*.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at the manual pages for Blender 2.8 and the image you're showing is for an even earlier version as far as I can remember. The selection icons for Blender 2.8 and above (including 3.3) are shown below.

[image]

And the icon for "Limit Selection to Visible" or also called *X-Ray* mode is here now:

[image: x-ray toggle]

Comment: Thanks Gordon. For some reason the later versions of the manual don't appear to show that toolbar as far as I can see. Plenty of YT videos around explaining the layout though...

Comment: In the manual for the current version you have the selection modes and x-ray explained here: [Modeling > Meshes > Selecting > Introduction](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/editors/3dview/introduction.html#header-region) and the x-ray mode also here: [Editors > 3D Viewport > Introduction](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.4/editors/3dview/introduction.html)

Comment: Ok. I didn't have time to look that far through the manual.

Comment: The trick is to enter keywords in the manual's search ;)

Comment: I usually get too many suggestions if I try that! :^)

Comment: @JohnEason exactly, those three icons are what I'm missing as per original question. Please look at the picture I've just added.

Comment: @Mark. See moonboots answer. - If you can't edit an object you won't see the editing icons! That's why it's so important to add images of your screen to questions.